# How to make a dynamic query using queryDSL when the number of parameters to be entered changes?

Tags: java, mysql, querydsl

I want to attach an eq() conditional statement to booleanExpression using or() as much as the list length.
What should I do?

For example

```
QStudyTime.studyTime.user.id.eq(rivalId).or(QStudyTime.studyTime.user.id.eq(rivalId2)).or(QStudyTime.studyTime.user.id.eq(rivalId3))
```

The above code is handled by method chaining when the number of rivaled is 3.
But my system doesn't have a fixed number of rivalId's.
What should I do in this case?
Can it be handled with a for statement?
Or is BooleanExpression a way to attach using the + operator just like String?

I solved it like this.

```
private BooleanExpression method(input parameter) {
List<Long> rivalIdList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < rivalList.size(); i++) {
   rivalIdList.add(rivalList.get(i).getRival().getId());
}
   return QStudyTime.studyTime.user.id.in(rivalIdList);`
}
```

Comment: Please check out this post https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1393

Comment: than u sir. I solved it.

Comment: Please post your revised code. Thank you